# php code after "if (isset($_POST..." is not running

Tags: php, html, forms

Exactly what the title says. My PHP written after an the an if statement to check if a text portion of a form has any value is not running. It works fine in one written earlier in my code, but not the second time.

Here is my whole code:

```
<?php include '../header.php'; include '../navigation.php'; ?>

<div id="pageContent">

<form name="format" method="POST" action="phpFunctions.php">
    Please input date: 
    <input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name"submit1" value="Format" />
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $new_date = $_POST['date'];
    $date = new DateTime($new_date);
    echo 'M-D-Y Format: ' . $date->format('m-d-Y') . '<br>';
    echo 'D-M-Y Format: ' . $date->format('d-m-Y');
}

?>

<form name="stringStuff" method="POST" action="phpFunctions.php">
    Enter string:
    <input type="text" name"yourString">
    <input type="submit" name"submit2" value="Parse" />
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['yourString']) && !empty($_POST['yourString'])) {
    echo 'ayyyyyy lmao';
    $new_string = $_POST['theString'];
    $trimmed_string = trim($new_string);
    echo 'ayyyyyy lmao';
    echo 'String Length: ' . strlen($new_string) . '<br>';
    echo 'Trim Whitespace: ' . $trimmed_string . '<br>';
    echo 'Lowercased: ' . strtolower($new_string) . '<br>';
    if(strpos($new_string, 'DMACC') !== false) {
        echo 'String contains DMACC';
    }
    else {
        echo 'String does not contain DMACC';
    }
}

?>

</div>

<?php include '../footer.php'; ?>
```

The portion of the code that isn't working is this portion after what I mentioned

```
if (isset($_POST['yourString']) && !empty($_POST['yourString'])) {
    echo 'ayyyyyy lmao';
    $new_string = $_POST['theString'];
    $trimmed_string = trim($new_string);
    echo 'ayyyyyy lmao';
    echo 'String Length: ' . strlen($new_string) . '<br>';
    echo 'Trim Whitespace: ' . $trimmed_string . '<br>';
    echo 'Lowercased: ' . strtolower($new_string) . '<br>';
    if(strpos($new_string, 'DMACC') !== false) {
        echo 'String contains DMACC';
    } else {
        echo 'String does not contain DMACC';
    }
}
```

Comment: You are clicking the `Parse` button? Have you put an `else` to confirm the conditional fails?

Comment: @chris85, yes, does nothing when I click the parse button and no I haven't. I'm still new to PHP and don't really know how to do that

Comment: @chris85, looks like I was missing a '=' in the name of the form

Comment: Yes, I saw answer below to debug yourself in the future uses `else`s so you know what the code is evaluating as. In this case you would have known `$_POST['yourString']` wasn't being sent and could have isolated the issue from there.

Comment: @chris85 awwwww okay that makes a lot of sense. Thank you dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed = , `name="yourString"`

```
<form name="stringStuff" method="POST" action="test_index.php">
    Enter string:
    <input type="text" name="yourString">
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Parse" />
</form>
```

Comment: ha, knew it was going to be something simple. Thank you. Should I delete this since it's something simple?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing name="yourString"

```
<input type="text" name="yourString">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Parse" />
```